# Reset Auto Increment in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I don't know how Auto Increment is set to 10. Every record inserted is incremented by 10. I fired this query - `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';`

output is -

```
auto_increment_increment    10

auto_increment_offset   3
```

I also tried resetting it - SET @@auto_increment_increment=10; but cannot change it.

How to get rid of it? I have 2,700,000+ records in one table and it will go on increasing.

This database is hosted on a remote mysql. Can i change this auto_increment myself or will have to ask server provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset them with the `set` command:

```
set global auto_increment_increment = 1;
set global auto_increment_offset = 1
```

Comment: SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment =1 

#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation. I have remote mysql. should i ask server provider ?

Comment: You need the DBA to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment):

```
SET auto_increment_increment = 1;
```

Comment: you need SUPER privileges to change it , use root user

Comment: i don't have super previlage its remote mysql.

Answer (score 0):

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with ALTER TABLE, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

To set intervals of increment:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```